# How to record API calls and store them in database

Tags: next.js, supabase

I'm using supabase and nextjs for this. i'd like to record any api calls and store them in a database like this

```
// api_path, called_at, called_by
"https://www.test.com/api/create_user",server.now(),"1"
"https://www.test.com/api/create_user",server.now(),"1"
"https://www.test.com/api/delete_user",server.now(),"1"
"https://www.test.com/api/analyze_user",server.now(),"1"

// user 1, called create_user twice, delete_user once, and analyze_user once.
// server.now() represents a date when the record was added to the server
```

is there a way to implement this?

I tried looking at supabase documentations on how to implement this but i can't find it, i was expecting that there was a way to intercept any incoming request and run functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about API calls to NextJS or to Supabase directly?

### To NextJS

Create a new table for API calls in Supabase. In the NextJS handler function, after executing the code, you can use supabase-js to insert a new item to the API call table in Supabase

### To Supabase directly

Create a new table for API calls in Supabase. Create a trigger function for the operations you want to track, such as an after-trigger for inserting a user, then in the trigger function, you can insert a new item to the API call table.